# ODE reducible to homogeneous equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the following ODE

$x'=\dfrac{2x-t+4}{x+t-1}$.

My attempt at a solution:

If I make the substitutions $x=y-k, t=s-h$ with $k,h$ constants, then $x'=y'$ and the original equation reduces to:

$y'=\dfrac{2(y-k)-(s-h)+4}{y-k+s-h-1}=\dfrac{2y-s-(2k-h-4)}{y+s-(k+h+1)}$. If I choose $k=\dfrac{5}{3}$ and $h=-\dfrac{2}{3}$, then the equation reduces to a homogeneous ODE.

Then, $y'=\dfrac{2y-s}{y+s} \iff y'(y+s)=2y-s$, I divide both sides by $s$ to get $\dfrac{y'(y+s)}{s}=\dfrac{2y-s}{s}$. When I make the substitution $z=\dfrac{y}{s}$, I get  that
$(z's+z)(z+1)=2z-1 \iff z's+z=\dfrac{2z-1}{z+1} \iff z's=\dfrac{-z^2+z-1}{z+1} \iff \int \dfrac{z+1}{z^2-z+1}dz=-\int \dfrac{1}{s}ds$

Here I got totally stuck, the problem is I don't know how to integrate the member of the left, the polynomial has complex roots so I cannot simplify that expression. What am I doing wrong? I've checked my work three times and I still can't see where my mistake is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good work so far.

Hint, using partial fractions, rewrite the integrand as:

$$\displaystyle \int \dfrac{z+1}{-z^2+z-1}~dz = \int \left(\dfrac{3}{2} \dfrac{1}{-z^2+z-1} -\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right) \dfrac{1-2z}{-z^2+z-1}\right)~ dz$$

- For the first integrand, complete the square, so we have $-\left(z - \dfrac{1}{2}\right)^2 -\dfrac{3}{4}$.
- For the second integrand, let $u = -z^2+z-1 \rightarrow du = (1 - 2z)~dz$

Comment: Thanks, this last part was driving me crazy. However, I have problems trying to integrate $\int \dfrac{3}{2}\dfrac{1}{-(z-\frac{1}{2})^2-\frac{3}{4}}dz$, should I decompose this into partial fractions? I've tried to but I couldn't.

Comment: Try a few substitutions: Let $w = z - 1/2$, so $dw = dz$. Rewrite as $-2( 1/(4w^2/3 +1)$. Let $p = 2w/\sqrt{3}$, so $dp = 2/\sqrt{3}~dw$. Now in form $1/(p^2 + 1) dp$.

Comment: Now I got it, next time I'll try to use cleverly these type of substitutions, thanks!

Comment: You got the hard part with your substitutions on the DEQ, this is just tricks with integrals! Keep up the great work! Regards

Comment: Nice and helpful hints! +1